# Select across many same schemas

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a project where each user is assigned to its own schema, which looks like this:

```
user_537        (schema)
    posts       (table)
    likes       (table)
    actions     (table)
user_538        (schema)
    posts       (table)
    likes       (table)
    actions     (table)
user_539        (schema)
    posts       (table)
    likes       (table)
    actions     (table)
```

Now I want to query across every `actions` table. I would like to get the result of:

```
select 
    537 as user_id, 
    count(*) actions
from actions 
UNION ALL

select 
    538 as user_id, 
    count(*) actions
from actions 
UNION ALL

select 
    539 as user_id, 
    count(*) actions
from actions 
UNION ALL
```

How can I do that without manually typing all schemas? For now I only managed to create a `select` that I can run to get what I want:

```
SELECT distinct 'SELECT ' || REPLACE(table_schema, 'user', '' ) || ' as user_id, count(*) as actions FROM ' || table_schema || '.actions UNION ALL' AS query 
FROM information_schema.tables
where table_schema like '%user%'
```

But I dont like this for 2 reasons:

- I have to manually copy output query to run it again
- I have additional `UNION ALL` at the and which I have to manually remove

Instead of this I would like to have a query that iterate over each schema, run a code and `unions` the result.

Comment: Both reasons you state for not liking your query are natural consequences of a **bad design**. Normalize your data and have a single `users` table containing all users. Your entire issue goes away.

Comment: There are valid use cases for having mutiple schema with the same table structure; e.g., using multiple schemas instead of multiple databases to reduce the number of databases that need to be maintained. This does not appear to be such a case.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have "many same schemas".

<sup>(Either that, or you should not be working on that project.)</sup>

You should have ***only one schema*** where each record in each table also contains the user id.

***That's the way relational databases are done.***

If unsure about relational database fundamentals, then a good starting point would be Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database)

Look for subjects like "normalization" and "denormalization" and you will understand exactly why having "many same schemas" is terribly, terribly wrong, and why if you do this you paint yourself into a corner and you cannot proceed any further.

It would not hurt to read a few good books on the subject, or take a course, before attempting to program relational databases.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, your database design should be revised (normalized), but as it is now you could generate your query like this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    l_schema_name TEXT;
    l_query TEXT := '';
    result record;
BEGIN
    FOR l_schema_name IN SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND schema_name != 'information_schema' LOOP
        l_query := l_query  || 'select ''' || l_schema_name || ''' as user_id, count(*) actions from '|| l_schema_name ||'.actions union all ';
    END LOOP;
    l_query := regexp_replace(l_query,'\sunion all\s$',';','g'); 
    for result in execute l_query loop
        raise notice 'Result: %', result;
    end loop;
END $$;
```

Implemented as a function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS TABLE(user_id text, actions integer)
AS $$
DECLARE
    l_schema_name TEXT;
    l_query TEXT := '';
    result record;
begin
    FOR l_schema_name IN SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%' AND schema_name != 'information_schema' LOOP
        l_query := l_query  || 'select ''' || l_schema_name || ''' as user_id, count(*) actions from '|| l_schema_name ||'.actions union all ';
    END LOOP;
    l_query := regexp_replace(l_query,'\sunion all\s$',';','g');
    return query execute l_query;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then to execute

```
select * from my_function();
```

Comment: But still this is like 2 steps: 1) get the code to execute, 2) execute. Is it possible to do in 1 step?

Comment: Yes it's possible, I'll add code for a single step.

Comment: I don't really like its printing results instead of showing them like from standard query execution. What I want to archive is run this whole `l_query` at once

Comment: That was just an example "ready to use" as an anonymous block. Now as a function you could execute it as a query at once.

Answer (score 0):

The following query gets the counts for `actions`, `likes`, and `posts` across schemas:

```
WITH s AS (
  SELECT schemata.schema_name,
         regexp_substr(schemata.schema_name, '\d+$') AS user_id
    FROM information_schema.schemata
  WHERE schemata.schema_name LIKE 'user\_%' ESCAPE '\'
)
SELECT s.user_id,
       (XPATH('row/actions/text()', x.counts))[1]::text::int AS actions,
       (XPATH('row/likes/text()', x.counts))[1]::text::int AS likes,
       (XPATH('row/posts/text()', x.counts))[1]::text::int AS posts
  FROM s
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT (XPATH('/table/row',
                  (QUERY_TO_XML(FORMAT($$SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.actions) AS actions,
                                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.likes) AS likes,
                                                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %I.posts) AS posts$$,
                                       s.schema_name,
                                       s.schema_name,
                                       s.schema_name
                                      ),
                                FALSE,
                                FALSE,
                                ''
                               )
                  )
                 )
           )[1] AS counts
  ) x
 ORDER BY s.user_id;
```

If only the `actions` counts are required, then the query can be simplified to use a single `XPATH`:

```
WITH s AS (
  SELECT schemata.schema_name,
         regexp_substr(schemata.schema_name, '\d+$') AS user_id
    FROM information_schema.schemata
  WHERE schemata.schema_name LIKE 'user\_%' ESCAPE '\'
)
SELECT s.user_id,
       t.actions
  FROM s
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT (XPATH('/table/row/actions/text()',
                  QUERY_TO_XML(FORMAT($$SELECT COUNT(*) AS actions FROM %I.actions$$,
                                      s.schema_name),
                               FALSE,
                               FALSE,
                               '')
                 )
           )[1]::text::int AS actions) t;
```